# Mensajes JSON siguen apareciendo los anteriores cuando no deberían salir mas

Tags: java, spring-boot

Tengo un servicios Rest en Spring Boot usando `BindingResult` y los errores encontrados los paso a json para indicar los campos que están mal pero cuando se envían los campos bien sale que se registro o actualizo el usuario pero sigue saliendo los mensajes anteriores.

Me explico:

Envió este json donde falta nombres y apellidos:

```
{
    "id": 1,
     "telefono": "45456456456",
    "correoalternativo": "angela@gmail.com"
}

// Recibo

{
    "usapellidos": "Ingrese los apellidos",
    "usnombres": "Ingrese el nombre"
}
```

Cuando envió este JSON con datos completos:

```
Envío: 
{
    "id": 1,
    "nombres": "Angela",
    "apellidos": "Martinez",
    "telefono": "45456456456",
    "correoalternativo": "angela@gmail.com"
}

Recibo:

{
    "message": "Actualizado",
    "usapellidos": "Ingrese los apellidos",
    "usnombres": "Ingrese el nombre"
}

// Si se actualizo dice en message pero los mensajes anteriores los sigue respondiendo
```

Controller del servicio Rest:

```
@PutMapping (value = "/update/information/{type}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    private ResponseEntity<String> updateInformation(@Valid @RequestBody UsuarioVO usvo, BindingResult result, @PathVariable String type) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) { // Aca envía el json con los campos que faltan o tienen error
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(Util.errorsJson(result));
        }
        String update = service.updateInformation(usvo, type);
        return ResponseEntity.status(update.equals("Actualizado") ? HttpStatus.OK : HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(Util.messageJson(update)); // Este es el return que me da el mensaje de 
     {"message":"Actualizado"}
    }
```

Metodos que crean el json

```
private static final JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    public static String errorsJson(BindingResult result) {
        for (FieldError error : result.getFieldErrors()) {
            json.put(error.getField(), error.getDefaultMessage());
        }
        return json.toString();
    }

    public static String messageJson(String value) {
        return json.put("message", value).toString();
    }
```

Ya hice debug y obvio solo cumple un return pero no se por que pasa es como si algo en memoria se quedara pegado en los return.

Intente de otra manera como se hace que es:

```
// Pero asi sigue pasando lo mismo
return new ResponseEntity<>(json,status);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si te fijas en la clase Util tu json es final cuando sucede la primera acción de validar campos ya ese json queda con los errores del result y cuando se actualiza el mensaje actualizado queda junto a los valores anteriores ya que la tienes como final y no estas cambiando valor alguno cada ves que usas:

Deberías hacerlo así y creo que funcionaria.

```
 private static JSONObject json = null;

    public static String errorsJson(BindingResult result) {
        json = new JSONObject();
        for (FieldError error : result.getFieldErrors()) {
            json.put(error.getField(), error.getDefaultMessage());
        }
        return json.toString();
    }

    public static String messageJson(String value) {
        json = new JSONObject();
        return json.put("message", value).toString();
    }
```